# SQL query to find any consecutive integer in my amount field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

So my data in the table looks like this:

```
amount  | ID
10918.6 | ABC
9999.99 | BCD
9999.89 | DEF
```

I need to find all consecutive digit (9999.99, 1111.11, 2222.22 etc except 0000.00) So from above example output should give only BCD. I have to check for 1k place only.

If I have 9999.99 and 99.99 it should only give me 9999.99.

Also if I have 989999.99 I have to consider this also as my accepted output

I can do this by using where clause -- column like '%9999.99' or '%1111.11' but I need to find the better way may be by regular exp etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using modulo you can strip away any digits above the 10k position, then check the values are in an accepted list.

```
WHERE
  (amount % 10000) IN (1111.11, 2222.22, 3333.33, 4444.44, 5555.55, 6666.66, 7777.77, 8888.88, 9999.99)
```

Or...

```
WHERE
  (amount % 10000) / 1111.11 IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

These avoid turning numbers in to strings, which is generally neither necessary nor prudent.